# Vertical aling text in UIWebview ios7

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to vertical-aling my text in `UIWebview`:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body> <div style=\"margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; height: 7em; line-height: 7em;background-color: %@; font-size: 25px; color:white\">%@</div></body></html>", myColor, string];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

[image]

It vertical align, but it have a white border. I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
  NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body style=\"width:100%%; margin:0px\"> <div style=\"margin:0 auto; width:100%%; text-align: center; height: 7em; line-height: 7em;background-color: %@; font-size: 25px; color:white\">%@</div></body></html>", @"#111111", @"Hello World...!!!"];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I found if text long it cuts him and add only that placed in width of webView. How I can make that text can be 2 rows and it show 2 rows, but not one.